# Problems using firebase authentication in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating an application with flutter and firtebase that contains email and password authentication.

I have already installed the firebase dependencies in the project and added the code to login.

Login code:

```
Future signIn() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _emailController.text.trim(),
      password: _senhaController.text.trim(),
    );
  }
```

But when I go to debug it, I get an error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I've tried several solutions but none of them worked, I even removed the firebaseAuth code and the application worked.